# How to remove several items in a list simultaneously

Tags: netlogo

How can I simultaneously remove several items in a list ? I have a list :

```
let list1 map [ -1 * ? ] reverse (n-values ( ( max-pxcor -  round (max-pxcor / 3) ) + 1 ) [?]) 
print list1
[-17 -16 -15 -14 -13 -12 -11 -10 -9 -8 -7 -6 -5 -4 -3 -2 -1 0]
```

For example, I would like to remove : 
- the last 4 items in the list :

```
[-17 -16 -15 -14 -13 -12 -11 -10 -9 -8 -7 -6 -5 -4]
```

- the last 9 items in the list :

  ```
  [-17 -16 -15 -14 -13 -12 -11 -10 -9]
  ```
- the last 13 items in the list :

  ```
  [-17 -16 -15 -14 -13]
  ```

Thank you very much for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`sublist`](http://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/docs/dictionary.html#sublist) to keep what you want from the list.

For example, remove the last 4 items in the list: `sublist list1 0 (length list1 - 4)`

You can generalize this into a function:

```
to-report remove-last-n [ lst n ]
  report sublist lst 0 (length lst - n)
end
```

which you can then use like: `remove-last-n list1 4`

Combining this with the unfortunately named [`sentence`](http://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/docs/dictionary.html#sentence), you can remove arbitrary sublists:

```
to-report remove-sublist [ lst position1 position2 ]
  report (sentence (sublist lst 0 position1) (sublist lst position2 length lst))
end
```

which lets you do

```
observer> show remove-sublist [-17 -16 -15 -14 -13 -12 -11 -10 -9 -8 -7 -6 -5 -4 -3 -2 -1 0] 2 13
observer: [-17 -16 -4 -3 -2 -1 0]
```